# C++ text file cannot be loaded

Tags: c++, readfile

So my driver looks like this:

```
#include "problem2.h"
#include "problem1.h"
#include "problem3.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
T convertString (std::string str){
    T ret;
    std::stringstream ss(str);
    ss >>ret;
    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    ifstream infile("text.txt", ios::in);
    if(!infile)
    {
        cerr <<"File could not be opend"<<endl;
    }

    SortedLinked mylist;
    int a;
    int b;
    string c;
    string d;
    string e;
    int f;
    char g;
    string h;

    string mystr;
    int mymin;
    int mysec;

    while(infile>>a>>b>>c>>d>>e>>f>>g>>h)
    {
        mystr = a+b;
        mymin = convertString<int>(e.substr(0,2));
        mysec = convertString<int>(e.substr(3, 4));
        replace(h.begin(), h.end(), '_', ' ');

        Runner M(mystr, f, mymin, mysec);
        mylist.additem(M);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

I put the text.file in the same folder, it worked in another PC that I just tried a few days ago. Right now, each time I tried to run it, it just straightly gives me "File could not be open". I don't know what went wrong. I even put one text.txt in the same directory as c++.sln, and another one in the same directory as my .cpp and .h files, just to make sure there is one text.txt that could be opened.

First, I tried via Xcode, I put my text.txt in both the project directory and the .cpp and .h directory. File could not be open.

Then, I tired via visual-studio, I did put .txt in the same directory as my .exe . 
"CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported. Defaulting to Windows directory.
File could not be open"

Comment: Have you tried giving the constructor of `std::ifstream` (`("text.txt",ios::in)`) a _absolute_ path instead of a relative path? That is `C:\Users\..`.

Comment: The file should be placed in the same directory where your .exe is placed. If you run the program in debug mode in Visual Studio, make sure it's in Debug folder. As additional check make sure that you have access rights to read the file under the user you're running .exe

Comment: Yes, I did put in the same directory as my .exe is placed.

Comment: How do you run it? Is current working directory the same one where these files are placed?

Comment: I edited and added the feedback, no idea what is saying

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is in this error message:

> "CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory. UNC
>   paths are not supported. Defaulting to Windows directory. File could
>   not be open"

You're launching the .exe from network share and cmd.exe changes your working directory to %WINDOWS% dir. Then program tries to open file by relative filename and surely fails. Copy exe and text file to local folder and it'll work ok.

Comment: thank you! I didn't realize  the other day its working because I was testing on my local drive, today Iam using my network folder.